# Partial locals are not being passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass some locals into a partial render in rails, however they are not getting passed.

```
<%=render :partial => "search_results", :locals => {:refinement => "all", :query => params[:search]}%>
```

The partial is being rendered in a view that has the `param[:search]` in it, that `params[:search]` is accessable inside of the partial without it being passed in as a local.

I'm trying to access the locals refinement and query by doing `params[:refinement]` and `params[:query]` inside of the partial, however they are not being recognized.

Comment: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/218539) No.

Comment: @timss, tags are allowed in titles when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title or when they disambiguate an otherwise vague title.  "Partial locals" is pretty confusing out of context.  "Rails partial locals" is much better.  Plus "Rails" is not the canonical tag on SO, ruby-on-rails is.

Comment: @OldPro Fair enough in this case, I was a little fast on the tags-in-the-title-omg-gun this time :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't access them via `params` - you just access the local variable, eg. `refinement` or `query`.

Answer (score 0):

Access them as `locals[:refinement]` or `locals[:query]` inside your partial. That should work.